# How can one determine if a singularity is ADE?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given an algebraic variety with a singularity is there an effective way to determine whether this singularity is or is not ADE.

I do know that this can be solved by computing the modality of the singularity and checking whether this is, or is not zero. However I do not know how to compute the modality of a singularity effectively.

I should explain my problem slightly better to reply to the questions being asked. I have a long list of surfaces with a singularity. For each of these I would like to know if these singularities are ADE or not.

One example would for instance be the surface with equation:
x^2+x^5+y^5+z^5.
I do not know how to determine the type of singularity at the origin.

Comment: The SINGULAR software can help.

Comment: Is it a surface singularity?

Comment: The case that interests me most is when the variety is a surface. The singularity is then either an isolated point or a curve.

Comment: ADE singularities are normal and therefore isolated, so perhaps that rules out some of your examples. They can be characterized as rational
Gorenstein surface singularities. This might be checkable depending
on what you know.

Comment: I guess I should ask, what data do you know about the singularity?  Do you have an honest presentation?  If so, there should be computer-ways to check this either via $D$-modules or via characteristic $p$ techniques.  I can write this down precisely in an answer if it would be useful.  Of course, there are a number of ways to check for Gorenstein / rational singularities as Donu mentions.

Comment: The example you give is not Du Val. See condition (3) of Theorem 2.1 in "The Du Val Singularities" by Miles Reid and also Section 2.2. In particular it says that the defining equation needs to have a monomial $x^i y^j z^k$ with non-negative coefficient and such that $2i + j + k < 4$. None of the terms in your equation satisfy this condition.

Comment: ADE singularities are exactly the double points of surfaces that are absolutely isolated; that is, they are isolated, and they remain isolated after iterated blow-ups; this is du Val's original characterization. Whether this can be turned into an actual algorithn I don't know.

Comment: I believe that the method described by Dustin can be applied at least in many of my examples. This will be of much help. Thanks.